# Unterschied zwischen »Applaus« und »Beifall«

Tags: difference

> ***Applaus**:*  Beifallsbekundung, insbesondere durch Klatschen mit den Händen
>
> ***Beifall**:* akustische Bekundung von Zustimmung und Gefallen einer Darbietung

Quelle: Wikipedia

Für mich besteht kein Unterschied zwischen den beiden Bedeutungen.

Bei einem Assoziationsspiel konnte ich feststellen, dass Deutsche das Wort *Applaus* bei weitem bevorzugen. Abgesehen davon weiß ich nicht, worin der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern besteht.

Comment: Woher hast Du die Information, dass Applaus bevorzugt wird? Ein [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=Applaus%2CBeifall&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CApplaus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBeifall%3B%2Cc0) spricht eher dafür, dass Beifall häufiger ist.

Comment: @Takkat Vielleicht war es reiner Zufall, aber bei einem Bild von klatschenden Menschen haben alle (5-6 Personen) "Applaus" gesagt, obwohl das gesuchte Wort "Beifall" war.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Applaus](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Applaus) kann man hören, [Beifall](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beifall) nicht immer.

Wenn hier bei SE eine Antwort nicht hochgezählt wird, kannst du sagen:

> Seine Ansicht fand keinen Beifall.

Comment: Stürmischer Applaus für diese bravourös kurze Antwort!